# How can I eject a CD via the cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file, eject

I have been trying to eject the cd drive with the use of the cmd.
However, I am stumped. Searching on the internet, I only found this answer:

```
eject D:
```

and a similiar answer

```
eject D: /I
```

Both of them do not work.

EDIT
Now people have found this answer on superuser,

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
colCDROMs.Item(0).Eject
```

However, I get an error:

colCDROMS.Item is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Im running windows 7, so batch files from xp may not work.

Comment: I'm asking a Meta question on this since I'm confused as well, and the tag makes no mention of when `batch-file` questions become off-topic.

Comment: The xp version is giving me problems.

Comment: On Meta: [When are 'batch-file' questions off-topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305964/when-are-batch-file-questions-off-topic).

Comment: Clearly, this is not possible in pure Batch. What exactly is it that you’re trying to accomplish? Have it run silently? Are other command line environments (Powershell) acceptable?

Comment: That's definitely not Batch-file scripting; it's VBS

Comment: https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/cd-rom/article.php/c5775/CDREXE--OpenClose-CD-Drives-Programmatically.htm

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can eject a cd with a batch file (this is part vbscript

```
@echo off
echo Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")  >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection       >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count-1             >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject                    >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo next                                       >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo oWMP.close                                 >> %temp%\temp.vbs
%temp%\temp.vbs
timeout /t 1
del %temp%\temp.vbs
```

This is not my work, I found it in  the stackoverflow community:

Post Link: [Batch Command Line to Eject CD Tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422571)
Answer Author: [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422247/bruno)
Date Answered: Feb 10, 2015

Comment: You need to state where you got it from: *This is not my work, I found it online.*. If you can't remember, you need to delete your answer for copyright reasons.

Comment: This answer is being discussed on Meta: [How do we deal with answers that do not attribute?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305965/how-do-we-deal-with-answers-that-do-not-attribute)

Comment: Technically speaking, this is a VBS solution, not a batch file solution.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, I don't mean to say that this isn't an appropriate answer for the question as stated, merely that perhaps the opening line "You can eject a cd with a batch file" should be modified slightly. If my system's configuration supports the execution of batch files but not of VB scripts, this answer will not work for me.

Comment: As of Dec 2016, Windows Defender on Windows 10 will detect the generated script as a virus when run

Answer (score 24):

You could use the `Shell.Application` COM object's `InvokeVerb` method.  From a cmd prompt, you can abuse a PowerShell one-liner thusly:

```js
powershell "(new-object -COM Shell.Application).NameSpace(17).ParseName('D:').InvokeVerb('Eject')"
```

You can also use Windows Scripting Host (VBScript / JScript) to invoke the COM object.  Here's an example using a hybrid Batch + Jscript script (save it with a .bat extension):

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "CDdrive=D:"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%CDdrive%"

goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera
var oSH = WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application');
oSH.NameSpace(17).ParseName(WSH.Arguments(0)).InvokeVerb('Eject');
```

If you prefer to have your script detect the drive letter for the CD drive, that can be arranged as well.  Here's a more complete version with comments explaining some of the non-self-explanatory values.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"

goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera

// DriveType=4 means CD drive for a WScript FSO object.
// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys4ctaz0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

// NameSpace(17) = ssfDRIVES, or My Computer.
// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

var oSH = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application'),
    FSO = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    CDdriveType = 4,
    ssfDRIVES = 17,
    drives = new Enumerator(FSO.Drives);

while (!drives.atEnd()) {
    var x = drives.item();
    if (x.DriveType == CDdriveType) {
        oSH.NameSpace(ssfDRIVES).ParseName(x.DriveLetter + ':').InvokeVerb('Eject');
        while (x.IsReady)
            WSH.Sleep(50);
    }
    drives.moveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Command line CD-eject oneliner:

In a bat file or directly in `cmd` this worked after first run of `wmplayer` on Windows 8:

```
powershell (New-Object -com "WMPlayer.OCX.7").cdromcollection.item(0).eject()
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `WMPlayer.OCX.7` will startled most of the anti-virus programs and there are some versions of windows that come without media player.
Here's a way with shell.application and invokeVerb function:

save this with `.bat` extension:

```vbs
@cScript.EXE //noLogo "%~f0?.WSF"  //job:info %~nx0 %*
@exit /b 0

   <job id="info">
      <script language="VBScript">
        if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 then
            WScript.Echo "No drive letter passed"
            WScript.Echo "Usage: " 
            WScript.Echo "  " & WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & " {LETTER|*}"
            WScript.Echo "  * will eject all cd drives"
            WScript.Quit 1
        end if
        driveletter = WScript.Arguments.Item(1):
        driveletter = mid(driveletter,1,1):

        Public Function ejectDrive (drvLtr)
            Set objApp = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" ):
            Set objF=objApp.NameSpace(&H11&):
            'WScript.Echo(objF.Items().Count):
            set MyComp = objF.Items():
            for each item in objF.Items() :
                iName = objF.GetDetailsOf (item,0): 
                iType = objF.GetDetailsOf (item,1): 
                iLabels = split (iName , "(" ) :
                iLabel = iLabels(1):

                if Ucase(drvLtr & ":)") = iLabel and iType = "CD Drive" then
                    set verbs=item.Verbs():
                    set verb=verbs.Item(verbs.Count-4):
                    verb.DoIt():
                    item.InvokeVerb replace(verb,"&","") :
                    ejectDrive = 1:
                    exit function:

                end if
            next    
            ejectDrive = 2:
        End Function

        Public Function ejectAll ()
            Set objApp = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" ):

            Set objF=objApp.NameSpace(&H11&):
            'WScript.Echo(objF.Items().Count):
            set MyComp = objF.Items():
            for each item in objF.Items() :
                iType = objF.GetDetailsOf (item,1):                                 
                if  iType = "CD Drive" then
                    set verbs=item.Verbs():
                    set verb=verbs.Item(verbs.Count-4):
                    verb.DoIt():
                    item.InvokeVerb replace(verb,"&","") :
                end if

            next
        End Function
        if driveletter = "*" then 
            call ejectAll
            WScript.Quit 0
        end if
        result = ejectDrive (driveletter):

        if result = 2 then
            WScript.Echo "no cd drive found with letter " & driveletter & ":"
            WScript.Quit 2
        end if

      </script>
  </job>
```

You can use it like (for more info -)

```
call eject.bat *
```

Comment: Even with `eject.bat *` it tells me `no cd drive found with letter d:`. Why might this be? If I right click the drive and choose "Eject", it ejects.

Comment: @BradTurek  - it could be the language (if it is not English) . Or if you have custom actions associated with the right click over cd drives. If you right-click on the CD/DVD device eject action should the 4th from the bottom (the default place).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a third-party application, you can use [Nirsoft's nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). On all the PCs I tried (from Windows XP to Windows 8), I could eject the disc using:

```
"C:\path_to\nircmd.exe" cdrom open X:
```

Where X is your disc drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 I use this little script. It works!

```
dim oWMP
  Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
  Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
  colCDROMs.Item(0).Eject
  set oWMP = nothing
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Op is using Windows 7 and he has already tried you script and said it didn't work.

Comment: is this script for cmd, powershell or smth else?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just use a [small 3rd party helper app named "Wizmo"](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm):

```
wizmo.exe open
```

Does the trick.