# How to eject and insert CD/DVD drive using command-line in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, dvd, compact-disc

As a Linux user I know that I can use command-line in Linux to eject/insert CD/DVD. Namely, the command to eject CD/DVD drive is `eject /dev/sr0` (or simply `eject`) and the command to insert CD/DVD drive is `eject -t /dev/sr0` (or simply `eject -t`).

Now, is it possible to do the same in Windows from CMD or PowerShell? Using Cygwin or WSL would be cheating so they don't count. I know I can use Windows' GUI to eject CD/DVD drive but not to insert it.

---

My question has been proposed as a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/972447). But I think that is only partially true. I will now explain why I think so.

It is easy to see that [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/972447) only asks for the command that ejects CD/DVD drive. My question asks for the command**s** that eject **and** insert CD/DVD drive. Therefore, answers to [that question](https://superuser.com/questions/972447) only answer one part of my question.

Comment: Go with the cmd `powershell (New-Object -com "WMPlayer.OCX.7").cdromcollection.item(0).eject()` solution since it's not drive letter specific and seems to work on Windows 10 and is a one-liner.

Comment: CD drives don't have a concept of open or closed. Sending the eject when it is open will close it. If possible. My cd drive by the way does not have a powered close.