# How can I identify which physical PC nearby I’m logged in on via SSH?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I’m currently in front of 20 computers and I don't know which one is mine!

I try the beep command but I can't hear any sound… Any ideas?

Comment: So you are removing into one of the 20 PCs? Do these PCs have monitors on them? Or at least a USB port?

Comment: Can you eject a CD/DVD drive?

Comment: Hostname cmd and/or serial number and/or eject CD tray.

Comment: On Windows you can get the serial via: `wmic bios get serialnumber`

Comment: @DougDeden How to eject a CD drive? :)

Comment: @JakeGould no monitor but some USB port

Comment: There are some ideas on how to eject a drive here: https://superuser.com/questions/972447/how-can-i-eject-a-cd-via-the-cmd

Comment: One idea if you don’t have an optical drive is to find a USB flash drive that blinks when written to. Insert it in the system, and then run a command to write to that USB flash drive. The light should flash. @DougDeden How do you know that the systems in place in 2019 have optical drives?

Comment: @JakeGould  I don't know that the system has an optical drive. That's why I asked. :-)

Comment: @DougDeden Fair enough! But with optical media becoming more and more obsolete and not really used, I guess we all have to come up with new techniques to find needles in server haystacks.

Comment: Are you Windows or Linux?

Comment: @rahuldottech linux :)

Comment: @Fractale Try my answer out then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Eject the cd/dvd drive
2. Stress the CPU - listen for fan sound.
3. Download a large file, seeing which HDD light stays on.
4. If you have access to a switch - check the mac address table to see where it's plugged in
5. Power it off!
6. using dmidecode see which serial it is, check the serials on the physical machines.
7. Turn the monitors on/off or screensaver on/off
8. xmessage to the screen.
9. aplay to play something via speakers/headphones

Answer (score 2):

Ejecting the CD drive was a solution and also stressing the computer to hear the fans scream!

Answer (score 1):

If on Linux, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install fancontrol
pwmconfig
```

It will turn all fans on to full speed, and you should be able to locate the PC. See more about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/249192).