# How to eject a drive from the command line in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I've been searching but only find this nonsensical page where some person is apparently lying about there being an "eject" command: https://www.techulator.com/experts/1789-How-eject-CD-ROM-using-command-Windows

But there is no such command:

> 'eject' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Also, pardon my frustration, but I'm sick and tired of "solutions" which require you to trust and install some sketchy third-party EXE. Why isn't something as incredibly basic as this built into the OS? It's baffling to me.

Or maybe it is. I sure cannot find it, however, and there is most definitely no "eject" command on my Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove USB device from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/443162/remove-usb-device-from-command-line)

Comment: [Dismount USB External Drive using powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/130887/dismount-usb-external-drive-using-powershell)

Comment: “Why isn't something as incredibly basic as this built into the OS?” Because Windows isn’t Linux. Use the GUI and do it, that’s the Windows way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I eject a CD via the cmd?](https://superuser.com/questions/972447/how-can-i-eject-a-cd-via-the-cmd)